# Toggle image source with vanilla javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

I am trying to swap an SVG logo image on click using Javascript. My script looks like this:

```
document.querySelector('.logo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src='logo-B.svg';
    document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src='logo-A.svg';
    })
```

The function works on the first click (when the third line of code is removed):
`document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src='logo-A.svg';`

However, I would like for it to switch back to the original `src` each time the logo is clicked — this should function as a toggle.

Is this done with an if statement? Or how is this achieved?

Many thanks

Comment: Please post a sample of HTML to better understand the classes `.logo` and `.logo-switch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need checks to see which logo is current and then replace it with another one. It can also be done via ternary operators, but `if-else` is more human-readable/understandable in this case.

As in OP you described the function works well on first click, so assuming the click handler is working fine, here is the condition below to add

```
document.querySelector('.logo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src.indexOf('logo-A') != -1) {
      document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src = 'logo-B.svg';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src = 'logo-A.svg';
    }
})
```

Comment: I like your thinking. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use an extra css-class for the `.logo` element and [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) that on click. The snippet is using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for that.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`logo`)) {
    return evt.target.classList.toggle(`right`);
  }
}
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Skip_to_left3.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right {
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Skip_to_right3.svg);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works :-

```
let replaced = false;

document.querySelector('.logo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#logo-switch').src = replaced ? 'logo-A.svg' : 'logo-B.svg';
    replaced = !replaced;
});
```

This uses a variable to keep track of whether or not the content was replaced on an alternate basis, if that makes any sense. Then based on that, it changes the source file of the images.

Comment: Smart thinking. Simple code and works well.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)?

```js
document.querySelector('.logo').addEventListener(
  'click',
  switchImage(
    document.querySelector('#logo-switch'),
    'logo-B.svg',
    'logo-A.svg'
  )
);

function switchImage (element, src1, src2) {
  var first = true;
  return function () {
    if (first) {
      element.src = src1;
      first = false;
    } else {
      element.src = src2;
      first = true;
    }
  }
}
```

*EDIT: using the snippet from @kooiinc*

```js
document.querySelector('.logo').addEventListener(
  'click',
  switchImage(
    document.querySelector('#logo-switch'),
    '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Skip_to_right3.svg',
    '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Skip_to_left3.svg'
  )
);

function switchImage (element, src1, src2) {
  var first = true;
  return function () {
    if (first) {
      element.setAttribute('href', src1);
      first = false;
    } else {
      element.setAttribute('href', src2);
      first = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.logo,
#logo-switch {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo">
  <image id="logo-switch" href="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Skip_to_left3.svg">
</svg>
```